# Delete remote branch with lease

Tags: git

Is there a way to delete a remote branch only if it is at the commit where my local repo thinks it is? Something like --force-with-lease, but for branch deletion instead of force-pushing.

This is what I fear:

1. I fetch branch X and confirm that it points to commit A, which is fully merged.
2. Unbeknownst to me, someone pushes commit B to branch X.
3. I delete the remote branch using `git push origin --delete X`.
4. Commit B is now unreferenced in the remote repository!

This is what I would like:

1. I fetch branch X and confirm that it points to commit A, which is fully merged.
2. Unbeknownst to me, someone pushes commit B to branch X.
3. I run ***some command*** that deletes remote branch X only if it still points to commit A.
4. The command reports to me that it failed because remote branch X has advanced in the meantime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to delete a remote branch only if it is at the commit where my local repo thinks it is? Something like --force-with-lease, but for branch deletion instead of force-pushing.

The answer appears to be, "`--force-with-lease`". If the remote repository has been updated since I last update my local repository, this fails:

```
$ git push --delete --force-with-lease  origin testbranch
To .../upstream
 ! [rejected]        (delete) -> testbranch (stale info)
error: failed to push some refs to '.../upstream'
```

Whereas this succeeds:

```
$ git push --delete origin testbranch
To .../upstream
 - [deleted]         testbranch
```